# How do i make a wordpress plugin to work on static websites

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I have a wordpress plugin that i want to make work on a simple static website, the plugin is a cloaker so im sure its not wordpress specific and can work anywhere, it contains a  php file for the cloaker and a folder with files as seen in the picture [picture of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr3og.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to use the plugin on a wordpress page (embed the shortcode in your editor, or more likely create custom page template without footer and header to have a clean page), and use an iframe on your html page to view the content of this page. I would recommend to use the page template because you probably won't need the header and footer of your page.

---

There are other ways, but you would need to use a php file, not a static html file to make things work.